# "HttpRequestContext " type and namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, .net

I have added **System.Web.Http.Controllers** dll however **HttpRequestContext** is not recognized by the system.

Error Message is: Type and namespace "HttpRequestContext" could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ).

VS version is 2012.

.NET Framework is 4.5

any idea on this?

Thanks!

Comment: 2012?!  Not so TechnoSavvy :)

Comment: According to [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httprequestcontext(v=vs.118).aspx] the DLL to use is actually System.Web.Http

Comment: give it a long shot!
**Sysyem.Web.Http.Contrllers.HttpRequestContext**
it works

Comment: @KeithNicholas yes it is VS premium 2012.

Comment: @IanofOz ,yep i have added System.Web.Http dll and in using i have added like **using System.Web.Http.Controllers**

Comment: @PrashanthBenny , i have tried that too however same error.

Comment: If the error still exists, you should carefully check your .Net versions. Maybe there is some conflict there.

Comment: are you able use the using for **System.Web.Http.Controllers**?

Comment: I'm with @Frits on this - main reason I've seen these mysterious issues is if you're referencing an assembly that is using a higher .net version than you're targetting. Sometimes this can be a bit obscure, in that an assembly may be pulled in via another assemblies nuGet reference for instance. Try dropping the need for HttpRequestContext and turn on verbose build output (via Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run), kick off a rebuild and see if something shows up.

Comment: Probably there is a huge conflict in the GAC.( I am not Sure)

Comment: What is the equivalent of httprequestcontext in net core